# How to set RequestHeader with WSClient and play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to make a GET call using `WSClient` but for some reason the `Authorization` header (or any header I try to set) is not present in the request headers.

```scala
ws.url("example.com")
  .addHttpHeaders("Authorization" -> s"Bearer $token")
  .get()
```

(using play 2.8.8)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think the headers are not present? The code you shared looks good.

Comment: The header is not present in request header list (chrome developer tools).

Comment: How would you see such request in Chrome Dev tools?! The request is issued by your app. Only the server (example.com) would be the place to check for headers presence.

Answer (score 0):

As @GaëlJ pointed out, I could not see the headers in Chrome devtools since it is a backend request... I was most likely looking at some random AJAX request.